# how can application yaml value inject at runtime in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vault

I want to change the value of `application.yaml` at loading time.

ex) application.yaml

```
user.name: ${name}
```

Here, I want to put this value by calling an external API such as a vault, rather than a program argument when the jar is executed with the name value.

First of all, I think I need to write code that implements `EnvironmentPostProcessor` and calls external API, but I don't know how to inject that value. can I get help?

```
public class EnvironmentConfig implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
        SpringApplication application) {
        // API CAll
        
        // how can inject yaml value??
    }
}
```

I don't know which way to orient myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1: doing it via EnvironmentPostProcessor:**

assuming you have registered you EnvironmentPostProcessor in `/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file:

`org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=package.to.environment.config.EnvironmentConfig`

all you need is to add your custom PropertySource:

```
public class EnvironmentConfig implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                                       SpringApplication application) {
        environment.getPropertySources()
                .addFirst(new CustomPropertySource("customPropertySource"));
    }
}

public class CustomPropertySource extends PropertySource<String> {
    public CustomPropertySource(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        if (name.equals("name")) {
            return "MY CUSTOM RUNTIME VALUE";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2: doing it via PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:**

A class that is responsible for resolving these palceholders is a BeanPostProcessor called `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)).

So you could override it and provide you custom `PropertySource` that would resolve your needed property like so:

```
@Component
public class CustomConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess, ConfigurablePropertyResolver propertyResolver) throws BeansException {
        ((ConfigurableEnvironment) beanFactoryToProcess.getBean("environment"))
                .getPropertySources()
                .addFirst(new CustomPropertySource("customPropertySource"));
        super.processProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, propertyResolver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ConfigurationProperties` for your properties and change it via an api like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class AppProperties {

    private String name;

    //getter and setter
}

@RestController
public class AppPropertiesController {
    @Autowire
    AppProperties prop;

    @PostMapping("/changeProp/{name}")
    public void change(@PathVariable String name){
        prop.setName(name);
    }
}
```